# Choosing the kind of current sensing method and the voltage of the testing signal for a DIY LCR meter

Tags: measurement, current-sensing

I have been designing my own LCR meter that uses the V-I method to make measurements. I have finished the sine wave generator and processor side, but I got stuck at the sensing part.

Here I have 3 types of sensing circuits:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFw9oE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The first one senses the current on the high side and measures the voltage on DUT on the low side. The next one is the opposite of the first one: DUT is on the high side and current sensing is on the low side.

The last one senses the current on the low side too, but with a transimpedance amplifier (I don't know if it can be moved to the high side).

Every one of them seems to have different pros and cons, and sometimes one says it is a pro whereas the other says it is a con (and vice-versa). This confused me much more.

I have made some tests and every one of them gives "slightly" different results on the same DUT values (approx. -/+30 nF on a 100 nF ceramic capacitor and -/+50 μH on a 100 μH inductor), and since they aren't precise/have high tolerances, my confusion still exists.

Which is the correct way to obtain accurate results? Also, can a 100 mV sine wave test signal be used to measure components in-circuit? Or should I stick to a 1 V signal and measure components individually?

It doesn't need to have lab-standard precision since I make the entire circuit from recycled components. I only want to measure things better than a multimeter with extra details.

Comment: Your schematics are barely legible. How do you interpret the results i.e. what do you use as a meter/monitor/display?

Comment: I measure both current and voltage with analog-to-digital converters and print their result on a serial monitor.

Comment: The measurement method could well account for significant errors if this is not done correctly. Demonstrate that you are measuring it correctly please.

Comment: I don't have it in my hands right now. It was built on a breadboard though, could that be an issue?

Comment: You are looking for reasons why 1 and 2 perform differently yet, without details of the implementation and the measurement system, this can only be speculated upon; look up common mode errors (measurement side). Hence why I left my comments and why you should take note of them. In other words, there is nothing fundamentally different between 1 and 2's performance except as generated by the implementation and your diagram is blurred and there is nothing that hints at the implementation errors.

Comment: No better advice than the Keysight Impedance Measurement Handbook: https://assets.testequity.com/te1/Documents/pdf/keysight/impedance-measurement-handbook.pdf